# How to further align two Grids e.g. onRowGroupOpened, onBodyScroll and onCellClicked?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I have two grids, one aligned to the other following the example from here:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/aligned-grids/#example-aligned-grids

However, the alignment only happens for a few events and I am interested in at least three additional navigation and position events so that the two grids can be more easily compared by mirroring the user gestures.

I attempted the following but doesn't work (doesn't trigger the event in the mirroring grid) for the `onRowGroupOpened` event and using the ref to the other grid accessing its api and submitting a `dispatchEvent`:

```
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import React, { useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';

const MirrorGridComponent = (props) => {
   const mirrorGridRef = useRef(null);

   const handleRowGroupOpened = useCallback((params) => {
      props.otherGridRef.current && props.otherGridRef.current.api.dispatchEvent(params);
   };

   <div className="grid ag-theme-alpine">
        <AgGridReact
          ref={mirrorGridRef}
          alignedGrids={props.otherGridRef.current ? [props.otherGridRef.current] : undefined}
          rowData={props.rowData}
          defaultColDef={props.defaultColDef}
          columnDefs={props.columnDefs}
          onRowGroupOpened={handleRowGroupOpened}
        />
      </div>   
};

export default MirrorGridComponent;
```